# Ads doesn't appear

Tags: android, libgdx, admob

I have a libgdx game and I successfully added Admob ads to it. When I run it on my physical device using Android Studio it shows ads as I used my device as test device but when I send it to another device from my phone it didn't show ads. It only showed a black rectangle with no ads as I set adView background to black colour.

My question is: should it be uploaded to the Google Play Store to show the ads or what?

Here is my code:

```
protected AdView adView;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    View gameView = initializeForView(new GameMain(), config);
    layout.addView(gameView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
    adView.loadAd(builder.build());
    adView.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000);
    adView.setAdUnitId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT    );
       adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    layout.addView(adView, adParams);

    setContentView(layout);
}
```

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the problem is the ad size is changing. The banner needs to be the *exact* size specified by Google.  If it's even a couple pixels smaller it will not display.  My guess would the new device you're testing on has a smaller screen or different aspect ratio, and that size difference is propagating down to the view where you have the advertisement embedded. Can't be sure without a little more info though.

Comment: I set adView size to SMART_BANNER and I think the problem is not in size as I set background color to black and a black rectangle appears with no ads

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify admob which are your test devices on which you want to see ads. For that use `addTestDevice`.

```
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .setBackgroundColor(0xff000000)
        .setAdUnitId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)       // Emulator
        .addTestDevice("FirstDeviceID") 
        .addTestDevice("SecondDeviceID") 
        .build();

adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It shows ads on my device which I add as test device but not other devices my question is why this happens or this is the normal as my app is not uploaded to Google Play Store

Comment: Ok you omitted that code. Then it may be because of size. Try to use normal banner. Set banner as `AdSize.BANNER` and assign `WRAP_CONTENT` as layout params. Refer to code in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646129/my-admob-ad-is-not-drawing-but-is-there-libgdx-admob-6-4-1) post.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code you load add before set the admob id. you just change this in your code

```
adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
adView.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000);
adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
adView.loadAd(builder.build());
```